# How would magic effect mass warfare?

Tags: dnd-5e, mass-combat

In the campaign world of Forgotten Realms, how could mass warfare be conducted between city states?  What magical options exist in 5th edition assuming the number of medium and high level NPCs is limited and that casters make up only a small percentage of the population?   What various tactics or strategies exist?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "too broad." Thousands upon thousands of volumes have been written on tactics and strategy in mundane warfare; adding a magical factor only broadens the horizons. If there's a fairly-specific "atom" of strategy or tactic that you're interested in, this might be a place for a question about that. Otherwise, you may be better served by [worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) or by [a forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970), or even just participating in [chat].

Comment: for your reference, here are [WB.SE questions about magic and war](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmagic%5D%5Bwarfare%5D+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: you also might want to look here on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/rpg/comments/1p1ui9/how_would_fantasy_armies_actually_do_battle/